# Display Images from Array with wp_get_attachment_image()

Tags: images

I'd like the client to be able to type any image ID (number) from any gallery / attachment and then displaying it with wp_get_attachment_image().

Here is my code:

```
if ( $images ) {
    foreach ( $images as $image ) {
       echo '<li>';
       echo wp_get_attachment_image( $images, 'thumbnail' ); // notice this part
       echo '</li>';
      }
```

When I do print_r $images, I get this array: 
    Array ( [0] => 318 [1] => 304 [2] => 301 [3] => 299 [4] => 297 )

and it works if I hardcoding the array, like

```
echo wp_get_attachment_image( 304, 'thumbnail' );,
```

but of course I'd like it to appear dynamically.

How to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `$image` instead of `$images` in the `foreach`. Voting to close as off-topic, being a pure PHP question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your code

pass `$image` in `wp_get_attachment_image` not whole array `$images`.

> Be careful when pass parameters

```
if ( $images ) {
    foreach ( $images as $image ) {
       echo '<li>';
       echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, 'thumbnail' ); // notice this part
       echo '</li>';
      }
```

Comment: You're right (have tested s_ha_dum's as well). Sorry guys :P

Answer (score 0):

You should do this before :

```
 $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'attachment',
   'numberposts' => -1,
   'post_status' => null,
   'post_parent' => $post->ID
  );
 $images = get_posts( $args );
```

to grab ID of post.

If outside the loop add `global $post;` before.

EDIT : nevermind ! anyway this could be useful for readers I guess (entire code)

Comment: EDIT: Just saw your edit ;)